# How can I "resume" a post-merge hook that was aborted due to merge conflicts?

Tags: git, githooks

I have a `post-merge` git hook that is based in part on https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/7996717. As expected, the hook fails to run if a pull introduces merge conflicts.

How might I go about handling the merge conflicts so that my hook can run as desired? My hook relies on diffs. If I manually resolve the conflicts and commit the updates, I no longer have any diffs so the logic in my hook is no longer relevant.

here's the hook (though I imagine it wouldn't really matter what is in here, if there are conflicts to begin with)

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "[post-merge] Commit done."
DIFFS="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id HEAD@{1} HEAD)"
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
GRN='\033[0;32m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
# Git hooks are not designed to be interactive. By default they don't have access to $stdin. 
# which meant that normal use of `read` was not working when used within the context of a git hook.
# This line restores keyboard access to stdin so that the dev can respond to the prompt that appears while the hook
# is running.
# Alternatively, we could forgo the confirmation and make package installation automatic, 
# though it seems better to allow dev to decide.

exec < /dev/tty

check_incoming() {
    # $1 is package.json 
    # $2 is handle_package_json
    echo "$DIFFS" | grep --quiet "$1" && eval "$2"
    exit 0
}

handle_package_json() {
    while true; do
    echo -e "${BLUE}[post-merge] PACKAGE.JSON UPDATED:${NC}"
    read -p "[post-merge] File may contain dependency updates. Run yarn install? (y/n) " yn
    if [ "$yn" = "" ]; then
        yn='Y'
    fi
    case $yn in
        [Yy] ) yarn install; break;;
        [Nn] ) echo "[post-merge] Installation deferred. You may need to manually update dependencies at a later point."; exit;;
        * ) echo "[post-merge] Please answer y or n for yes or no.";;
    esac
    done
}

if [[ -n "$DIFFS" ]]; then
    check_incoming package.json handle_package_json;    
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How might I go about handling the merge conflicts so that my hook can run as desired?

You cannot do this from a hook, because—as you found—the hook never gets run.

What you need to do is have users invoke your own command *instead of* running `git merge`.  Have your command run `git merge` and inspect the result (including exit status) to decide whether the merge succeeded.

(Note that this means they cannot run `git pull` either, since `git pull` runs `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  You might need to provide them a command to substitute in for `git pull`, if they're the kind of people who like the `git pull` command.)

(As an aside, it seems like it might make sense to check whether `package.json` might need merging *before* kicking off the `git merge`: find the merge base yourself, and use `git rev-parse` to extract the three hash IDs, for `HEAD:package.json`, `<merge-base>:package.json`, and `<theirs>:package.json`.  If the hash IDs match don't match, you can even extract the files themselves, with `git show` or `git cat-file -p`, to do pre-merge inspections if desired.  If all three hash IDs match, the merge is trivial: all three files are the same and Git will just keep `package.json` as is.  If merge-base and theirs match, but `HEAD` differs, Git will keep the `HEAD` version. If merge-base and HEAD match, but theirs differs, Git will take their version.  If all three *don't* match, Git will attempt to merge json data as if it were line-oriented plain-text, which is likely to produce nonsense.)